# Java Jndi connection gets full before max connection limit

Tags: java, jndi

I have five applications connected to each other,
In this I have set max connection limit for each application 50 in context.xml file.
like this,

```
<Resource name="jdbc/pcrmnet" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://url:5432/mydb"
          username="test" password="test123" maxActive="50" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>

<Resource name="jdbc/accountmsnet" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://url:5432/mydb"
          username="test" password="test123" maxActive="50" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>

<Resource name="jdbc/society123net" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://url:5432/mydb"
          username="test" password="test123" maxActive="50" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>

<Resource name="jdbc/hdpcrmnet" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://url:5432/mydb"
          username="test" password="test123" maxActive="50" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>

<Resource name="jdbc/facilitybookingnet" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://url/mydb"
          username="test" password="test123" maxActive="50" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>
```

but if connection 50 is full in one application, server doesnt allow us to create connection object in remaining 4 application..
whats missing please help.